# Linking a PHP Extension Written in C

Tags: php, automake, php-extension, php-internals

**Edit: Revising My Question**

When building an external PHP module in C, how do I link shared objects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your C extension code uses a shared library, you need to declare that in the `config.m4` file.

I **strongly** recommend using the [`ext_skel`](http://php.net/internals2.buildsys.skeleton) script that's included in the PHP source to generate a skeleton config.m4:

`./ext_skel --extname=myextension`

Since you're linking to a library, by convention you should use the `--with-myextension` options (as opposed to `--enable-myextension`).  Uncomment the relevant lines in the config.m4 and fill in the details of your lib.

Something like the following:

```
  # --with-myextension -> check for lib and symbol presence
  LIBNAME=the_lib_your_extension_needs # you may want to change this
  LIBSYMBOL=some_symbol_in_the_lib_you_extension_needs # you most likely want to change this 

  PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,
  [
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH($LIBNAME, $MYEXTENSION_DIR/lib, MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_MYEXTENSIONLIB,1,[ ])
  ],[
    AC_MSG_ERROR([wrong $LIBNAME lib version or lib not found])
  ],[
    -L$MYEXTENSION_DIR/lib -ldl
  ])
```

Then to build it, run:

```
phpize
./configure --with-myextension
make
```

Finally you need to copy your module (or `ln -s`) to wherever your system expects to find it.

If that all worked then `php -m` should include your module in the list.

Unfortunately I've never found a good online reference to PHP's config.m4 commands - the books for this are [Sara Golemon's Extending and Embedding PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232704X) and also parts of [George Schlossnagle's Advanced PHP Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325616).

There's a reasonable beginners guide to creating PHP extensions by Sara Goleman [here](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/), but for the meat you really need her book.