# add two shared libraries in php extension. WHO?

Tags: php, c++, php-extension, php-ini

I have a sharedlib.cc and a sharedlib.h code that contains classes and methods. I wrap this up and created a shared library called `MySharedLibrary.so.`

I would like to work with my .so library inside a php code. So I've created a config.m4 file , a php_code.cc file and a php_code.h file in order to make the extension from php possible. I DON'T WANT TO include in the config.m4 file the sharedlib.cc. I would like to include instead the MySharedLib.so because I don't want to expose my sharedlib.cc code. Besides I have others library that I also included in my .so library. Need some help.

**EDIT:!!**

**I DON;T WANT TO INCLUDE IN THE CONFIG.M4 THE FILE: sharedlib.cc. I want to include only the sharedlib.h and MySharedLibrary.so (the lib that contains both the sharedlib.cc and sharedlib.h)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY()` macro in `config.m4` will achieve this.

You can find some examples here: http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486

edit: you may need `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH()` if your shared lib isn't somewhere that the linker will find it.

edit 2: looks like this was covered before; the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508430/linking-a-php-extension-written-in-c/1513479#1513479) provides good example code.

Comment: do i need to add both the php_code.so and my MySharedLibrary.so in the file php.ini?

Comment: could u please give me a shot example with how to add in php extension (config.m4) multiple .so files? APPRECIATE A LOT!! THANK YOU