# How to expose a C library to a RESTful web service

Tags: php, linux, rest

I have a shared library written in C Language on Linux environment.
How to expose those shared library API's to REST based PHP WebService?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.structure.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to do it the "exec" way, you will have to do some work before you can get it working directly from within php.

Check this http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/ tutorial.

You will have to write a config.m4 file and put PHP specific includes and variables in your C code.

Check this answer:

[Linking a PHP Extension Written in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508430/linking-a-php-extension-written-in-c/1513479#1513479)

It's a good example.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little ugly, but you can do methods in your PHP REST Api to call the process via `system`, `exec`, `passthru`... parse the info returned by the library and return the result in json format by the PHP Api.

Comment: Totally agree with @andy

Comment: @andy: That's a meaningless statement - anything can be insecure if done incorrectly. Still, it's a good idea to think carefully about security implications of making code available remotely via an API.