# Linking PHP Extension with shared Library

Tags: php, php-extension

I am currently trying to add my own written shared library to my Extension(OSB). But when i try to run `./configure --with-osb` I get the error that my lib(OSC) is not found.

My config.m4:

```
PHP_ARG_WITH(osb, for osb support,
[  --with-osb        Include osb support])

if test "$PHP_OSB" != "no"; then
  LIBNAME=osc
  LIBSYMBOL=mute

  PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,
  [
    PHP_ADD_INCLUDE($OSB_DIR/include)
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH($LIBNAME, $OSB_DIR/lib, OSB_SHARED_LIBADD)
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_OSB,1,[ ])
  ],[
    AC_MSG_ERROR([wrong $LIBNAME lib version or lib not found])
  ],[
    -L$OSB_DIR/lib -ldl
  ])

  PHP_SUBST(OSB_SHARED_LIBADD)
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(osb, $ext_shared)
fi
```

In my extension directory i have a folder where the header of my lib is lying and a lib directory where the osc.so lies in.

But somehow I am not able to find the library itself.

PKG-Config is not a possible solution.

I tried to follow the solution of this post [Linking a PHP Extension Written in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508430/linking-a-php-extension-written-in-c) . But I dont know why it wont work for me.

Another [solution](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch14_04.htm) I tried.

I also tried other solutions but nothing worked for me.

**EDIT**
I am using PHP8.0

Comment: Have you compiled OSC by your self? in this case you may need to include it's dir on the configure step. `./configure --with-osb=DIR`

Comment: yeah i compiled it by myself but even when i give the argument to the path of the lib it says that it hasn't found it. But thx for the input

Comment: BTW, I noticed that you have a typo. you are trying to `./configure --with-osb` while you are loading another lib `LIBNAME=osc`, osb / osc.

Comment: should the lib name be the same as the extension name? I thought they could be independent from each other. Because my lib's name is osc. I know it's confusing but i can't change the names. OSB(PHP Extension's name)should be using functions defined in OSC(A "shared Object"/"Library" ) because the OSC is used also in other projects.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it can share a different names. but it needs at least to be defined as following: `[  --with-osc        Include osb support])` "note the with-osc instead of with-osb". However, as mentioned, most likely it is because the ocs lib path, it would be helpful if you shared your compiled version path, and the `./configure --with-osb=DIR`

Comment: My compiled osc is lying under `~/osc/out` and i am trying to run `./configure --with-osc=/home/mint/osc/out`

Under osc/out is:
osc.so
osc.o
osc.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now i got it fixed.
For everyone here is the solution to this problem. Seems pretty obvious after trying many other.

So if you want to invoke your own library in Linux you want to use [Libtool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) to generate a Library on the System which then allows to to use the PKG-Config from PHP and you are not any more forced to use Path Search and other Settings.

After that it's easy to link to this lib using a config like this:

```
PHP_ARG_WITH([myextension],
  [for myextensionsupport],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-myextension],
    [Include myextensionsupport])])

if test "$PHP_MYEXTENSION" != "no"; then

  PKG_CHECK_MODULES([MYLIBRARY], [mylibrary])
  PHP_EVAL_INCLINE($MYLIBRARY_CFLAGS)
  PHP_EVAL_LIBLINE($MYLIBRARY_LIBS, MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)

  dnl If you need to check for a particular library version using
PKG_CHECK_MODULES,
  dnl you can use comparison operators. For example:
  dnl PKG_CHECK_MODULES([MYLIBRARY], [mylibrary>= 1.2.3])
  dnl PKG_CHECK_MODULES([MYLIBRARY], [mylibrary< 3.4])
  dnl PKG_CHECK_MODULES([MYLIBRARY], [mylibrary= 1.2.3])
  PHP_SUBST(MYEXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)

  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_MYEXTENSION, 1, [ Have myextension support ])

  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(myextension , file.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

And then run only

```
phpize
./configure
make
make install # If you want to export the extension to the PHP-Source
```